# Forms using mixed fields from various entities and rending with Twig in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

## Problem

I have a Symfony2 2.3 project that consists of many entities (models). These models range from address, person, application and others amongst this. I needed a form to represent different steps in an online application. The application steps all contained many fields from various entities.

So at first; I created matching FormTypes and Twig templates to match. Everything was fine until I needed to mix the forms up.

For example, for one form, I needed:

- First name
- Surname
- DOB
- Postcode (from address entity)
- Application started date (from application entity)

As you can see, the form consists of 2 extra elements from different forms.
Thus I had the problem of binding the three layers together with use of Doctrine; entity, from type and twig template. (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions)

## Current Solution

Thus so far, I have my models setup as they should be. So address details are within the address entity and personal details are stored in the person entity.

I have then created all my FormTypes of how I want them to output to the screen, with the mixed fields in. Therefore, I have for example a Step-1 FormType that has:

- First name
- Second name
- DOB
- Address house number
- Address postcode

Then in Twig simply output the fields. I was then going to add custom validation and custom methods to save the data to the DB, to the various tables. I came to the conclusion that I had to do this because none of the forms can map to a single entity.

## What I Need

If anyone could shed some light on this and provide me with some examples, it would greatly appreciated!

As you can see below, I have some fields that I have hard-coded that represent different properties from other entities and a FormType.

- I need a way to have all these entities in normal form.
- Have various FormType steps that have mixed properties from these various entities
- Some FormTypes will embed other FormTypes, e.g. address - as the user can add 3.
- Have Twig tempalte that will simply render each individual widget.
- A controller that loads the form, checks it is valid and saves values to their own tables.

It may be, that I must create a totally custom method that saves the values individually but I was hoping for a 'Symfony way' of achieving this.

## Example code

Assume all getters and setters created with Doctrine.
Assume all Doctrine Mapping added with one-to-one relationships to link tables.

**Person entity:**

```
private $id
private $first_name
private $last_name
private $dob
```

**Address entity**

```
private $address_number
private $address_postcode
private $address_lived_years
private $address_lived_months
```

**Application entity**

```
private $id
private $plan
```

**AddresType**

```
$builder->add('address_number', 'text')
        ->add('address_postcode', 'text')
```

**Example mixed form: Step1Type**

```
$builder->add('first_name', 'text')
        ->add('last_name', text')
        ->add('dob', 'date')
        ->add('address_1', 'collection', array('type' => new AddressType()));
        ->add('address_lived_years', 'text')
        ->add('address_lived_months', 'text')
        ->add('plan', 'text')
```

## Twig

```
{{ form_start(step_1_form) }}

    {{ form_label(step_1_form.first_name, 'First Name') }}
    {{ form_errors(step_1_form.first_name) }}
    {{ form_widget(step_1_form.first_name) }}

    ... etc

{{ form_end(step_1_form) }}
```

## Controller to bring it all together

```
$step_1_form = $this->createForm(new StepOneType())->createView();

return $this->render('MyBundle:Application:apply_step_1.html.twig', array(
                    'step_1_form' => $step_1_form));

// Code needed to load form getForm() and handleRequest()
```

Comment: symfony 1.3-1.4 had a way of "merging" forms together - perhaps Symfony2 has something like that?

Comment: Cheers halfer. It does needed have one using the getForm() method and assigning it a new instance of the entity. All that you would need to do, is then persist() it to save it to database.

The problem is, I can't see to find a standardized way of doing this  where my forms don't map 1-1 to my entity; but form mapping to many entities.

Comment: Yes, I _think_ 1.x merging did that, though I never quite spent the right amount of time to get my head around it. The idea was that a customer form (for a single customer) could be merged with an orders form (for many orders), to create a form in which all the above could be edited. I can't offer much more help than that, other than to suggest that "merge form" might be a good set of search keywords!

Comment: Symfony2 has an `inherit_data_option` that allows merging/sharing of fields between form entities, but I've only had time to skim your question so I am not sure how applicable it is to your question in its entirety. However it's worth a look: http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/inherit_data_option.html

Comment: Alternatively, it seems to me that if you are creating a form to populate multiple entities in several steps, that this is a presentation layer problem - would it be an option to create one large form, and customise the form view in the template to present each step  - perhaps using javascript (jQueryUI tabs etc.) to display each step?

Comment: Thanks Darragh. The inherit_data_option is interesting; however it won't solve this particular problem. Further to your second comment, there has to be separate forms per step. I am leaning towards saying my FormTypes are correct but tying it all together is the problem.


Thus, being able to persist and flush all of this mixed data easily. I suppose I must create new instances of ALL entities and populate what data is available at that step. Then at the next step, reload the saved entity and re-populate with new data.

It always helps to talk it out,

Amarjit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any [Doctrine association mappings](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html) defined there. Since you are asking the user to enter some data from person entity and some data from the address entity I assume you need to save them and mark them as related (as in, the row saved in the `person` table should be somehow linked to the row saved in the `address` table). For your case I think that OneToOne should be the case (one person is linked to one address... and vice-versa). Though, in real life, this is not really the case.

You should than define specific ***Type** classes (`PersonAddresType`, for instance) to hold **ONLY** the wanted fields for that specific situation and use the doctrine relations and embedded forms there. See documentation for this on S2 site. For your case I think that [embedding a single object](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedding-a-single-object) is the right start.

If you need more details (or maybe some example)... let me know. I'll try to write some lines of code, if necessary.

Comment: Sorry Sergiu for not being clear. Doctrine mapping setup. Everything is set to one-to-one for now.


So for each entity (e.g. Person), I should create a FormType (PersonStep1Type) that will only contain the properties I need for Step 1? e.g. 'first name' and 'last name'? And then for Step 2, a PersonStep2Type with only the DOB?


Then I'm guessing in the controller, I just create/reload an instance of Person entity and populate.


Thus you are saying I should create a new FormType for each step per each entity? Rather then creating a Step1, Step2, for all my steps which combine the properties?

Comment: After reviewing my code, you may be onto winner Sergiu; with the ["embedding a single object"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedding-a-single-object) suggestion. I will develop further and see if this provides the solution. Cheers

Comment: Embedding forms within forms was the correct method. I created a specific form, per entity, per step; of the properties I wanted exposed in the twig template. This further allows me to persist using Doctrine easily. Thanks to all for answering.